# ActiveModel::Serializers embed: :ids, include: true not sideloading data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember-data, active-model-serializers

I'm running a Rails 4.2 - AMS 0.9 app, and I have (for illustrative purposes) 3 models: `Foo` has_one `Bar`, has_many `Baz`es. I am only getting the ids in the response, and not the sideloaded items. Is there a config option, or something I've missed?

My AMS class is:

```
class FooSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   embed :ids, include: true
   has_one :bar, key: :bar    ## For ember-data; it doesn't like "_id"
   has_many :bazes, key: :bazes

   attributes :id, :etc

end
```

There're quite a few topics on AMS throughout StackOverflow, and I read many before posting, but this has just left me totally stumped.

Answer (score 2):

After a bunch of experimentation, I had to call the following in the controller:

```
format.json { render json: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@foos, each_serializer: FooSerializer), root: :foos }
```

The `root: :foos` (incidentally, not even "true" worked, nor did `self.root = true` or `self.root = :foos` in the serializer itself) is the key bit.

Comment: I cannot believe this is the solution (it worked for me). This is a far cry from just `render json: @foos` like you should be able to do. I wonder why it doesn't just automatically work?

Comment: Oh lord have mercy I figured it out: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-9-stable#use-serialization-outside-of-actioncontrollerbase

Answer (score 0):

@Ted's answer worked for me on arrays, but when I tried to serialize in a show method, I couldn't use `AciveModel::ArraySerializer` of course. While researching *why* Ted's answer worked, I came across this little line in the AMS documentatiopn

> When controller does not inherit from ActionController::Base, include Serialization module manually

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::Serialization
end
```

link: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-9-stable#use-serialization-outside-of-actioncontrollerbase

Since my rails app is api only, this was what I needed.